# On Click Of select option show List Box

Tags: html, html-parsing

I am developing a form in which I need to show a list box when the user selects one of the options in a select box.  This means that initially the list box will be hidden, and when the user clicks on an option the list box should be displayed.

Thanks in advance for your quick response, Tanu

Comment: can u elaborate more on this..

Comment: i have elaborate it. Please suggest the solution.

Comment: Do add some comments as to whether the solution was useful or not..

Answer (score 1):

This could be done using jQuery easily.

```
 <select id="Univ">        
        <option value="1">DU</option>
        <option value="2">IIT</option>
        <option value="3">MU</option>
        <option value="4">BHU</option>
    </select>
    <select id="branch">
        <option value="1">Bio</option>
        <option value="2">Chemistry</option>
        <option value="3">Physics</option>
        <option value="4">Engg</option>
    </select>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#branch').hide();
            $('#Univ').click(function () {
                $('#branch').show();
            });
});
```

Dont forget to include the jQuery reference file in your HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```